# Observation on the priority order of application properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

When using Spring Cloud config server, I have observed the below behavior. Please let me know, if my hypothesis is correct regarding the behavior.

1. If the application-${env}.yaml/properties have the `server.port` property set, I cannot override the value, even by passing `-Dserver.port`
2. If I do not inherit the property defined in the spring cloud config, then I will be able to provide the value inside the `application.yaml/property` of the application
3. If the property is defined inside the application's `application.property/yaml`, I can override the value from the command line by passing the `-Dserver.port` option.

Is my assumptions right based on the above behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, spring cloud config value can't overwrite by default . We can change to override with property `pring.cloud.config.allowOverride=true`

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#overriding-bootstrap-properties